# PDF columtext shrink to fit using iText or iTextSharp

Tags: java, c#, pdf, itext

I have a function to relay a stamp on top of a field in PDF to serve as filling richtext field.

```
    public void FillRichTextField(AcroFields pdfForm, PdfStamper pdfStamper, string fieldName, string value)
{
    System.Collections.Generic.IList<AcroFields.FieldPosition> pos = pdfForm.GetFieldPositions(fieldName);
    //tell itextSharp to overlay this content 
    PdfContentByte contentByte = pdfStamper.GetOverContent(pos[0].page);
    //create a new paragraph
    Paragraph par = new Paragraph();
    //parse html
    var mh = new SampleHandler();
    //Bind a reader to our text
    using (TextReader sr = new StringReader(value))
    {
        //Parse
        XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(mh, sr);
    }
    for (int k = 0; k < mh.elements.Count; k++)
    {
        par.Add((IElement)mh.elements[k]);
    }

    //create a ColumnText to hold the paragraph and set position to the position of                   the field
    ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(contentByte);

    ct.SetSimpleColumn(pos[0].position.Left, pos[0].position.Bottom, pos[0].position.Right, pos[0].position.Top);
    ct.AddElement(par);
    int status = ct.Go();
    bool fits = !ColumnText.HasMoreText(status);

}
```

The paragraph got cut off so I'd like to resize/rescale the paragraph to fit in the ColumnText, there does not seem to be a way of doing that. I can't initiate a new font as the paragraph contains richtext data that has it's own font. I guess my best bet is to convert the paragraph into a scalable image then resize to fit?

Or if there is a better way of filling richtext field so that all text fit in with the style maintained please let me know.

Comment: You say you *fill richtext field*. To me it looks more like you stamp your text onto the regular page content at the position where the field is. Filling fields usually involves adding content to the field itself and its widget annotations...

Comment: I changed the language, you are correct. I'm stamping the text onto the richtext field because I think there is no better way of filling in the richtext field. Let me know if I'm wrong. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: *I think there is no better way of filling in the richtext field.* - Well, theoretically there should be but I have not yet seriously had to deal with that task. That been said, if that way of *filling in* is ok for you, one can scale the coordinate system to make things fit. Essentially you have reserved an area with a rich text field and want to make some rich text content fit there, correct?

Comment: Yes, the area is defined and the rich text content is just a stamp lay over to it. I guess my question is how I can scale the stamp field

Comment: Ok, I'd like to try something. Can you share a sample PDF (via a google drive or drop box public share) and a rich text string `value` (large enough to cause the issue)?

Comment: Hi @mkl, I sent an email to your wir-sind-cool mail box, please let me know if you have any question about the email that I sent. I appreciate your help!

Comment: You shared the rich text; can you also share a sample PDF?

Comment: Sorry, all was delayed by Jonas, I've sent you the PDF, let me know if you didn't receive it.

Comment: Does my answer answer your question? Or are there still open questions concerning the shrinking?

Comment: Hi @mkl, I don't thin it scales to the box.

Comment: *I don't thin it scales to the box* - Not exactly, right, after all the tested magnification are separated by a 50% rise. To get a more correct factor, you could e.g. thereafter test with 10% falls until it does not fit anymore, and then again with 1% rises until it does fit once again.

Comment: Thanks for taking your time sending me replies! For some reason, when I applied this to my formal code, it said error opening, the file is damaged. Also, the rectangle is just to mark the field so you can see, I don't want the rectangle show in my pdf.

Comment: *For some reason, when I applied this to my formal code, it said error opening, the file is damaged.* - that indicates that there is some error in your formal code. *Also, the rectangle is just to mark the field so you can see* - in that case simply drop the rectangle drawing instructions.

Comment: sorry, I'm a newbie to the itext, still trying to understand your code. what the lines are doing after ct.Go(), isn't that writing to the pdf? seems like then you add another template (contentByte.AddTemplate... contentByte.Stroke())?

Comment: As you saw yourself, you could not resize the stuff added by the `XmlWorker` directly. Thus, the code in my answer takes a small detour: it draws the stuff on a separate canvas, the `PdfTemplate template`, and adds a resized version of that canvas to the actual page content: `contentByte.AddTemplate`. Thereafter the code removes the original field (`pdfForm.RemoveField`) and explicitly draws the rectangle (`contentByte.Rectangle`, `contentByte.Stroke`) the field implicitly used to draw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change your method `FillRichTextField` like this, it scales down the content it draws to fit the form field rectangle. Furthermore it removes the form field as it would hide the drawn text.

```
public void FillRichTextField(AcroFields pdfForm, PdfStamper pdfStamper, string fieldName, string value)
{
    System.Collections.Generic.IList<AcroFields.FieldPosition> pos = pdfForm.GetFieldPositions(fieldName);
    PdfContentByte contentByte = pdfStamper.GetOverContent(pos[0].page);
    Rectangle fieldRectangle = pos[0].position;

    PdfTemplate template = contentByte.CreateTemplate(fieldRectangle.Width, fieldRectangle.Height);

    ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(template);
    XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(new ColumnTextElementHandler(ct), new StringReader(value));

    for (float factor = 1; ; factor *= 1.5f)
    {
        ct.SetSimpleColumn(0, 0, factor * fieldRectangle.Width, factor * fieldRectangle.Height);

        if (!ColumnText.HasMoreText(ct.Go(false)))
        {
            ct.Go();
            template.Width = factor * fieldRectangle.Width;
            template.Height = factor * fieldRectangle.Height;
            contentByte.AddTemplate(template, 1 / factor, 0, 0, 1 / factor, fieldRectangle.Left, fieldRectangle.Bottom);

            pdfForm.RemoveField(fieldName);

            contentByte.Rectangle(fieldRectangle.Left, fieldRectangle.Bottom, fieldRectangle.Width, fieldRectangle.Height);
            contentByte.Stroke();

            return;
        }
    }
}
```

in combination with this handler class

```
public class ColumnTextElementHandler : IElementHandler
{
    public ColumnTextElementHandler(ColumnText ct)
    {
        this.ct = ct;
    }

    ColumnText ct = null;

    public void Add(IWritable w)
    {
        if (w is WritableElement)
        {
            foreach (IElement e in ((WritableElement)w).Elements())
            {
                ct.AddElement(e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The result is not yet satisfying though:

[image: Screenshot]

As you see there is some overlapping text.

The code above renders what it receives from the XMLWorker. Thus, either my XMLWorker usage is incorrect or the input is bad. The scaling code as such (i.e. the `for` loop) should be correct, though.